Doveadm troubles making command line instuctions work for all users
Using Dovecot 2.3.15 and Maildir storage.
doveadm help shows me:

 expunge      [-u <user>|-A] [-S <socket_path>] [-m] <search query>
 search       [-u <user>|-A] [-S <socket_path>] <search query>


Which implies that expunge will work on "All" users (-A), (I had read other posts and comments elsewhere that expunge won't do this for all users).
So;
Before deleting I want to test the results with a Search;
I tried a series of simple SEARCH tests to list all emails with a certain subject line from the server mailboxes (dozens of mailboxes)
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search -A Subject 'Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise'
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search -A HEADER Subject 'Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise'
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search HEADER Subject 'Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise' -A
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search Subject 'Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise' -A

but all of these give blank results, no errors, just nothing, blank.
(3rd party listing show there are 67 emails on the server with this subject line)
I've read through https://doc.dovecot.org/main/core/man/doveadm-search-query.7.html  but can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm expecting a search list result output on the command line.
Further, I can't get any command line results (as root) from searches specifying either -A or -u such as:
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search -u 'myaddress@mydomain.com' FROM 'known_email_address@myInbox.org'

But this still returns no result. What am I missing to make Search (and by extension expunge by subject line) work from the command line?
Thank you

[root@basic ~]# doveadm  mailbox list -u 'myaddress@mydomain.com'

this DOES correctly list the mailboxes in my email. But the search returns no results.
UPDATE:
I have carried out a search specifying a user and it appears to work:
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search -u 'myaddress@mydomain.com' SUBJECT 'A Subject line of an email in my mailbox'
9d999b00d1d92a5457400000993f9ae9 28857
[root@basic ~]# doveadm search -A SUBJECT 'A Subject line of an email in my mailbox'
[root@basic ~]#

This shows that the concept seems to work on a per-user basis but doesn't work when focusing on -A for all users.
How can I make the above work for all users?
OR
How can I generate a dovecot / doveadm list output of current users?

Have you tried double quotes ("): doveadm search HEADER Subject "Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise" -A?

@Paul yes I've tried using double quotes as well.

That exact command works on my system.

@Paul what is your system? Ours is CentOS 7.9 . Also I think that the command is wrong I don't need to specify the HEADER and the Search, eg I have also tried [root@basic ~]#  doveadm search -A SUBJECT 'Melt fat fast! Without diet or exercise' but that still gives no result.

@Paul please see my update to my question. Thanks.

CentOS 7 is EOL.

@Paul that's pretty irrelevant to this question. The issue is structuring a doveadm query rather than about CentOS. Anyway thanks for your time.
